# Find the third largest score from the list of students and scores using Python

Tags: python, function

Using the given lists given, how do I find the name who has the third largest score?

the data is:

```py
names = [Andi, Budi, Charlie, Dilan, Echa]
score = [80, 80, 80, 100, 90]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```py
names = ['Andi', 'Budi', 'Charlie', 'Dilan', 'Echa']
scores = [80, 80, 80, 100, 90]

print(sorted(zip(names, scores), key=lambda x: x[1])[-3][0])
```

output:

```
Charlie
```

**Explanation**:
With `.zip` you zip those lists together, then you sort them based on second item in the tuple which is the score. Til now you have a sorted list of tuples. You want the third highest score so `[-3]` and because you need the name of the person `[0]`.

---

If the scores are `[80, 80, 80, 100, 90]`, it gives you the **first** person encountered in that index. If you need all of them, You need a second iteration too see all persons have that score:

```py
names = ['Andi', 'Budi', 'Charlie', 'Dilan', 'Echa']
scores = [80, 80, 80, 100, 90]

sorted_list = sorted(zip(names, scores), key=lambda x: x[1])
third_highest_score = sorted_list[-3][1]
print([name for name, score in sorted_list if score == third_highest_score])
```

output:

```
['Andi', 'Budi', 'Charlie']
```

Comment: If it is 3rd highest, why not count from 0 to have index 2 instead of -3?

Comment: @DevangSanghani You can do that. Since the length of the list is not predefined, you can have a little extra calculation like `lst[len(scores) - 3]`. I liked negative indexing here because it easily counts from the end. Did you mean that ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to (1) sort unique scores, (2) take the nth highest score, and (3) to keep exclusively those names which correspond to the nth highest score when iterating over both lists.

Example:

```
names = ['Andi', 'Budi', 'Charlie', 'Dilan', 'Echa']
scores = [80, 80, 80, 100, 90]
nth_highest = 3

sorted_unique_scores = sorted(list(set(scores)))  #(1)
max_nth_highest = - len(sorted_unique_scores)
nth_highest_score = sorted_unique_scores[max(- nth_highest, max_nth_highest)]  #(2)
filtered_names = [name for name, score in zip(names, scores) if score == nth_highest_score]  #(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For another approach, you may use following. First a dictionary is created from two list. Then, it was ordered thanks to  "Counter".

```
from collections import Counter

names = ["Andi", "Budi", "Charlie", "Dilan", "Echa"]  
scores = [80, 80, 80, 100, 90]

sample_dict = {}

for name in names:
    for score in scores:
        sample_dict[name] = score
        scores.remove(score)
        break

k = Counter(sample_dict)

best_3 = k.most_common(3)

print(best_3)


for i in best_3:
    print(i[0]," :",i[1]," ")
```

see output:

Dilan  : 100
Echa  : 90
Andi  : 80

print(best_3[2]) # gives 3rd best one.

Comment: You don't need the `scores.remove(score)` and the `break` statements.